# React Bootstrap Table: Inline Style to Change Background Color Based on Value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I have a problem that seems simple but I'm not sure how to get around it. Basically, I have a React Bootstrap `Table` that renders table data coming in from an API. What I would like to do is to change a row color to green if a specific value in the data is greater than zero... here is an example:

```
const TableComponent = ({ fixtures }) => {
    return (
        <Table>
            <tbody>
                {fixtures.map((fixture) => (
                    <tr
                        key={fixture.id}
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: 'green'
                        }}
                    >
                        <td> {fixture.value1} </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    );
};
```

So this defaults to a green `backgroundColor` for the row at all times. Is it possible to write a function so that, if `fixture.value2` or `fixture.value3` is greater than zero, the `backgroundColor` is green, but set to default otherwise?

Comment: did you try like this? <tr style={fixture.value2>0|| fixture.value3>0?{backgroundColor: 'green'}:{}}> {fixture.value1} </tr>

Comment: Thanks George, I didn't realise you could write functions inside the curly braces for the style prop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.
Try like this.

```
const TableComponent = ({ fixtures }) => {
    return (
        <Table>
            <tbody>
                {fixtures.map((fixture) => (
                    <tr
                        key={fixture.id}
                         style={fixture.value2>0|| fixture.value3>0?{backgroundColor:'green'}:{}}
                    >
                        <td> {fixture.value1} </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    );
};
```